# Connection issue in C# WinForms application with multiple forms

Tags: c#, winforms

When I run the application, are all forms in the app loaded/initialized even though I have not opened them yet? (I.E. Form.Show)

this is how I closed the connection in the login form:

```
if (usertype == "UT1") //admin rights
{
    //GET LOGGED USER
    Home_Admin homeAdmin = new Home_Admin();
    homeAdmin.SetUsername(username);

    cString.Close();
    this.Close();

    System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(OpenHomeAdmin));
    t.Start();
}
```

And how I got to the back up form from Home_Admin's menu strip

```
private void backUpToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackUp BackUpForm = new BackUp();
    BackUpForm.Show();
}
```

I am trying to create a back up of my database and it works perfectly if I run only the back up form. If I start the app from the very beginning, it says back up failed the database is in use. I already closed the connection from login to the form where I will launch the back up form and even set a

```
if(conn.State = connectionState.Open)
{
     conn.close();
}
```

prior to the back up procedure. **Is there any way I can just kill all connections to the SQL database > back up > and then restore the connections?**

**BACK UP CODE**

```
    public void BackupDatabase(String destinationPath)
    {
        SqlConnection cString = new SqlConnection();
        cString.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\MY_THESIS\\WORKING FILES\\NNIT-RMS.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

        if (cString.State == ConnectionState.Open) 
        {
            cString.Close();
        }

        try
        {
            //MY SERVER
            String userName = "NNIT-Admin";
            String password = "password";
            String serverName = @"RITZEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS";

            ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName, userName, password);
            Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

            Backup BackupMgr = new Backup();
            BackupMgr.Devices.AddDevice(destinationPath, DeviceType.File);
            BackupMgr.Database = "NNIT DB";
            BackupMgr.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
            BackupMgr.SqlBackup(sqlServer);

            MessageBox.Show("Back up saved!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + " " + ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
```

**FORM LOAD**

```
private void BackUp_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    string date = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
    string year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
    string month = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();

    Filename_txt.Text = "NNIT-RMSDB_" + month + date + year;
}
```

**Error message**
http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/8541/error1lj.jpg

Comment: When an application starts, you need to instantiate each form before hand. This is **not** done automatically.

Comment: You need to add _a lot_ more information and code. How do you start your backup process? What is the _full_ exception message?

Comment: If that's so then that means what ever code I have in their form load is not loaded unless I open the form through form.show, correct? @Oded

Comment: Correct. You need to load the form for the event handler to execute.

Comment: @user1141604: Why should a class be initinalized that is yet not used? So yes, Form_Load occurs before it is shown for the first time.

Comment: Then why am I getting an error? I have no connection in the entire back up form.  I will copy the error wait

Comment: I don't see your point @TimSchmelter, I have no connections in form_load. See code above ^

Comment: First, `cString` is a bad name for a connection. Next, you need to start **disposing** objects which implement `IDisposable`, by wrapping them inside `using` blocks. You should not keep your connection open during your form's lifetime, instead just open it, perform a tranaction, then dispose it.

Answer (score 3):

In this piece of code:

```
SqlConnection cString = new SqlConnection();

cString.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\MY_THESIS\\WORKING FILES\\NNIT-RMS.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

if (cString.State == ConnectionState.Open) 
{
    cString.Close();
}
```

You are instantiating a *new* connection and never opening it. The code in the `if` clause will *never* be hit.

Your mistake is assuming that the *new* connection is the only one - there may be *multiple* connections (opened in other forms and never properly closed) - some not even from your application (for example, using SQL Server Management Studio - having an open query window to your database will mean there is an open connection).

Comment: Exactly what my question is about. I have multiple connections since I have multiple forms in my application. Before I got to my backup form I passed through 2 forms which has connections in it. I closed the connection in those two forms already prior to opening Backupform using Form.Close. and still the error appears

Comment: @user1141604 - How? How have you done so? With `using` statements?

Comment: @user1141604 - Yes. Can you post the code you use for closing connections in the question?

Comment: @user1141604 - You should really wrap the creation of connections and commands in `using` statements to ensure proper closing and disposal. This _may_ be the issue, but without you taking a look at the server to see what is still connected to the database, there is no way to tell if it's your application or not.

Comment: How will I be able to check what is connected to my database in SQL Server?

Comment: And I'm positive that the issue is coming from my Application. I ran the same code on two different applications (testApp and this one, where the code is appearing) it worked perfectly on the testApp

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for to kill all connections to db is to take it offline, other solutions almost fail

```
using (SqlConnection sqlcnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE DB_NAME SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", sqlcnn);
                sqlcnn.Open();
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlcnn.Close();
            }
```

Add the above code before your backup or restore code and then your backup or restore will work even if you have open connections to your db.